# 'React/RCTMockDef.h' file not found

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run my React Native app for iOS on Xcode: "'React/RCTMockDef.h' file not found". I'm on React Native v0.67.2 and I've already tried doing cd ios and pod install. Can anyone help? Thanks

[image: error that i'm seeing in xcode]